# Built an indicator view with CAShapelayer. How to ease continous input?

Tags: ios, core-animation, sensors, easing, indicator

I'm making an app that shows a sensor input value using a custom made indicator view, that moves around a CAShapeLayer with a dot, based on the continous sensor input.

However, I'd like to avoid too much flickering, so I want to add some easing (I already have the desired function which will make it look as desired). But i want to do some continous animation that moves the dot to the proper position but with some delay etc, based on current and previous values etc.

I.e. when I shake the device, the dot movement should be reluctant but as soon as it's not shaken anymore, the dot show move to the proper point.

I don't want to set up a timer that moves the dot if needed every 1/60th second, I'd rather prefer some built in methods for that.

Can anybody give me some suggestions about what APIs to use, or some code examples to follow? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `CAShapeLayer` then you'll want to use `CAAnimation`s. A `CABasicAnimation` would probably do the trick. You'd just animate a change in the path that's installed in your layer.

`CAAnimation` is a pretty complex subject. I suggest googling "CAShapeLayer animation" to get you started.